# Sound overlap and delay issue in my Java code

Tags: java, audio

I am working on a project for fun and would appreciate some help. Currently I am trying to implement sound into my game. As it stands right now, this is the code I have...

```
public static volatile boolean shutdown = false;

//This is a method to play sound

public static void play(String name) {
    shutDown();
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Main.class.getResource(name));
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInputStream);
                clip.start();
                while (!shutdown) {
                }
                clip.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
    thread.start();
}

public static void shutDown() {
    shutdown = true;
    shutdown = false;
}
```

As it stands, the code I wrote works. Although I have a few issues. At times when I run this twice it can play the music over each other. Another issue is sometimes there will be a noticeable delay before my sound will start. Any help would be great!

Comment: Might try to add `audioInputStream.close();` after the `clip.close();`

Comment: No luck but thanks.

Comment: Another possibility is to add a `clip.stop()` before the `clip.close()`.  I saw this in some Java sound source file examples found here:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html  ... there could be other things there that you may find to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are using Clip in a way that goes against its designed use. Clips are meant to be pre-loaded in memory and left there in a state that is ready to call when you need them. Then, when it becomes time to play the cue, you only execute the start method, or maybe reposition the frame position back to the beginning and then call start.

With what you have now, you can expect all sorts of latency issues. Every time you call play, the system has to load the entire file into memory. It won't even start playing until this stage has totally completed. If the cue is so large that you don't want to leave it in RAM, the the best thing to do is to use a SourceDataLine instead of a Clip. With SourceDataLine, playback will start playing after only a buffer's worth is loaded to memory.

I'm not clear from what you have written if you want to have concurrent playback of cues or not, so I don't know how to answer that part of your post yet.

Also, I want to recommend a class I wrote specifically for game audio use. It is called AudioCue and you can check it out at [Java-gaming.org](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/audiocue-an-alternative-to-clip-for-2d-games/38294/view.html). The code source is available under a BSD license (in other words, it is free, and you can edit it). I worked pretty hard to make it as much like other Java classes as possible, with a lot of work put into the Javadocs/API. The class is similar to Clip, but a little simpler for *fire-and-forget* playing, as well as additional capabilities (e.g., good volume, panning and speed controls). No "library" to load, just paste three classes into to your project and feel free to tinker with it.